# Virtualization on Windows: boot from ext4 partition on USB

Tags: windows, virtualization

With which virtualization solution can I boot an Ubuntu install in an USB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) can do it.

It doesnt allow you to directly boot from USB, but it does allow you to attach a physical device to a virtual drive.

So the trick is to create a virtual drive pointing to your USB stick, and then adding that drive to the vistual machine.

**Step 1** - Find your USB key ID

- Right Click on My Computer > Manage > Disk Management
- Find your USB. `Disk 1` means the ID is `\\.\PhysicalDrive1`.
- Numbering starts from 0 (your first HDD), so USB stick will be 1, 2 or even 3.

**Step 2** - Create the Virtual Drive

- In terminal ( menu > cmd ), issue the following command:

  ```
  VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "%USERPROFILE%\usb.vmdk" -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive1
  ```
- Im assuming your USB is PhysicalDrive1
- The drive will be created in C:\Users\youruser\usb.vmdk

**Step 3** - Add the drive to the virtual machine

- Just use Virtualbox's GUI
- Select the Virtual Machine > Settings > Storage > Add Attachment > Choose existing Disk
- Browse for the newly created `usb.vmdk`

More details can be found in this [amazing article](http://agnipulse.com/2009/07/boot-your-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/)

Comment: Do mention the command to change the directory first, else readers will not know why the command doesn't work until the source article is read.

Comment: Sorry, AskUbuntu ommited the first "\" in "\\.\PhysicalDrive1". I guess i need to fiddle with formatting so it displays right. But, AFAIK, theres no directory change necessary.

Comment: It is necessary, I asked the same in the Ubuntu Forums and was told to do the same with `VBoxManage`. but it did not work. I can see why `/bin` directory is there in Linux/Unix now.